# How to find the maximum number of matching data?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

Given a bidimensionnal array such as:

```
 -----------------------
|   | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
|-------------------|---|
| 1 | X | X | O | O | X |
|-------------------|---|
| 2 | O | O | O | X | X |        
|-------------------|---|
| 3 | X | X | O | X | X |       
|-------------------|---|
| 4 | X | X | O | X | X |       
 -----------------------
```

I have to find *the largest set of cells currently containing `O` with a maximum of one cell per row and one per column*.

For instance, in the previous example, the optimal answer is 3, when:

1. row 1 goes with column 4;
2. row 2 goes with column 1 (or 2);
3. row 3 (or 4) goes with column 3.

It seems that I have to find an algorithm in `O(CR)` (where `C` is the number of columns and `R` the number of rows).

My first idea was to sort the rows in ascending order according to its number on son. Here is how the algorithm would look like:

```
For i From 0 To R
    For j From 0 To N
        If compatible(i, j)
            add(a[j], i)

Sort a according to a[j].size

result = 0

For i From 0 To N
    For j From 0 to a[i].size
         if used[a[i][j]] = false
             used[a[i][j]] = true
             result = result + 1
             break

Print result
```

Altough I didn't find any counterexample, I don't know whether it always gives the optimal answer.

Is this algorithm correct? Is there any better solution?

Comment: reminds me of sudoku...

Comment: Your requirements aren't quite clear... In your example is there a reason row 1 can't go with either column 3 or 4 (you state only that it can go with column 4)? Similar for row 2 (I see 1, 2, or 3, not just 1 or 2)...

Comment: Based upon your description of what's valid, why isn't (1,3) also valid?

Comment: I think there are many valid sets of unique tuples for any given table in this problem, but the size of these sets is all the same.

Comment: @twalberg: Because it doesn't lead to the optimal answer. If row 1 go with column 3, no row will go with column 4, and the answer won't be optimal (you will get 2). I don't know whether I am clear. :/

Comment: @mbratch: It is indeed valid, but not optimal. I have rephrased my explanations a little bit.

Comment: Ah, so the "new" tuples are not independent. So you're looking for essentially "the largest set of cells currently containing `O` with a maximum of one cell per row and one per column"?

Comment: @Kirilenko, OK thanks. You didn't define 'optimal' in your original problem. ;) And your criteria were stated as "distinct and valid".

Comment: @twalberg: Yes, that's it!

Comment: @mbratch: My mistake, sorry.

Comment: I think you are trying to do [maximum bipartite matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#Maximum_matchings_in_bipartite_graphs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off Billiska's suggestion, I found a nice implementation of the "Hopcroft-Karp" algorithm in Python here:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/123641-hopcroft-karp-bipartite-matching/

This algorithm is one of several that solves the maximum bipartite matching problem, using that code exactly "as-is" here's how I solved example problem in your post (in Python):

```
from collections import defaultdict
X=0; O=1;
patterns = [ [ X , X , O , O , X ],
             [ O , O , O , X , X ],        
             [ X , X , O , X , X ],       
             [ X , X , O , X , X ]] 

G = defaultdict(list)

for i, x in enumerate(patterns):
    for j, y in enumerate(patterns):
        if( patterns[i][j] ):
            G['Row '+str(i)].append('Col '+str(j))

solution = bipartiteMatch(G) ### function defined in provided link
print len(solution[0]), solution[0]
```